# ts2304 cannot find name 'OnInit'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I've worked through the Angular superhero tutorial. It all works.

If i close the cmd window running NPM, then re-open a CMD window and reissue the NPM START command I get two errors

```
src/app/DashBoard.component.ts(12,44)  TS2304 : Cannot find name 'OnInit'.
src/app/hero-list.component.ts(16, 434)  TS2304 : Cannot find name 'OnInit'.
```

I can resolve this by removing

```
Implements OnInit
```

from both these classes, 
run NPM start 
re-add them  (simply CTL Z in the editor)
make some change , save. 
The app recompiles and I am off and running.

I have 4 classes that implement this function. I have studied them and can not figure out what makes 2 fail...

I have read posts that reference TS2304, but this seems to be a generic Function/Variable/Symbol not found message ...

I don't know what to post. I'm happy to post any of the code.
Is this caused by errors in modules this depends on (hero.ts)?

Here is one class that is failing in this manner. 
This is the hero-list.component.ts file
(at various points in the demo/online examples, this is also named Heroes.component..)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Hero  } from './hero';
import { HeroService  } from './hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'hero-list',
  templateUrl: './hero-list.component.html' ,
  providers: [HeroService],
  styleUrls: [ './hero-list.component.css']
})



export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit   {

    heroes : Hero[];
    selectedHero: Hero;

    constructor(
        private router : Router ,
        private heroService: HeroService
        ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getHeroes();
    }

    onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
        this.selectedHero = hero;
    }

    getHeroes(): void {
        this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
    }

    gotoDetail() {
        this.router.navigate(['/detail', this.selectedHero.id]);
    }

    add(name: string): void {
        name = name.trim();
        if (!name) { return; }
        this.heroService.create(name)
            .then(hero => {
                this.heroes.push(hero);
                this.selectedHero = null;
            });
    }
    delete(hero: Hero): void {
        this.heroService
            .delete(hero.id)
            .then(() => {
                this.heroes = this.heroes.filter(h => h !== hero);
                if (this.selectedHero === hero) { this.selectedHero = null; }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: You will get the same error if you misspelled 'OnInit'. In my case I used 'onInit'. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You have to import OnInit.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 13):

The [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) fails to mention that you need to add the import of [OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) to TypeScript file *app.component.ts*:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: In my case, the import was there before as you mentioned with correct upper/lowercasing, but I got this error mentioned in the question. Re-running 'ng start' in VS Code terminal did not help. Then I copied + pasted this line exactly over the existing one, re-ran 'ng start' and it worked again. Strange!